# Add Chart to Joined report

Tags: reporting, joined-reports

Is it possible to add chart in Joined report? I tried to do this but the chart is not visible when running the Report.

Comment: It sounds like you've already added the report. Is the report not showing or is it empty? Can you provide a screenshot to help explain the problem?

Comment: So does that mean you could add the chart but it just doesn't render?  Can you tell us more about the report and chart.  I've added bar charts to joined reports without problem.

Comment: did you check if  the report displayed at the bottom or top of the report?

Answer (score 2):

From Chapter 10 of [Force.com Platform Fundamentals](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/fundamentals/salesforce_creating_on_demand_apps.pdf):

> Joined reports let you create different views of data from multiple report types. In a joined
>   report, data is organized in blocks. Each block acts like a “sub-report,” with its own fields,
>   columns, sorting, and filtering. You can add a chart to a joined report. For example, in the
>   following sample, the joined report pulls data from two report types related to the Positions
>   object. Together, the report shows applications received from job ads posted for each
>   position.

[image]

Clearly, the answer is "yes, you can add charts to joined reports". The [Analytics Workbook](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/workbook_analytics/workbook_analytics.pdf) includes a tutorial on creating a joined report. Unfortunately, that tutorial adds the chart to a Dashboard *after* the joined report has been run, not as part of the report itself.